# ASP.NET MVC calling partial view from another partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page that uses a couple of partial views.  My first partial view has some options that when the user selects, and presses a button, it gets data from a database and renders the other partial view on that page.

What is the best way to go about this?  I've not really done much in MVC before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, views are only concerned with rendering models from your controller. You need to set up a controller action to accept the view options and then render the second partial. Roughly...

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View(); // Foo.aspx is not given a model, so don't show second partial
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(bool option1, string option2)
{
    var data = repository.GetData(option1, option2);
    var model = new FooModel(data);
    return View(model); // Foo.aspx is given a model, so show second partial
}
```